# Facebook Chat bot not working for public

Tags: chatbot, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-chatbot

I have a chat bot working fine for a single page.
My app is currently live and available to the public.
I generated page tokens using Facebook Login.
But I want to integrate same chat bot with other pages also.
I follow below guidelines to subscribe other page in my app.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/subscribed_apps
But other pages are not hitting my webhook.
Screenshot of may app and messenger review are below.
[image: My App Review Screenshot]
Second image of messenger review
[image]

Please suggest me how i integrate my app for multiple pages.
Am I missing any step?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What permissions did you grant when you added the page subscription?

Comment: Permissions -
user_photos, manage_pages, pages_show_list, publish_pages, public_profile

Comment: When you call `GET /v2.11/{page-id}/subscribed_apps` does it list the app as subscribed?